# Appending Multiple Lines Into a File But Skip If They Already Exist

Tags: shell-script, configuration, posix, here-document

I deal with a lot of config files when I'm working with Linux and because I like automating the setup process I make good use of creating automated shell scripts.

I want to find a fast and efficient way of specifically appending multiple lines of code together to the end of file but checking if the lines of code exist together as a whole and skip if they do. If I was to keep re-running a script I don't want duplicate blocks of text being appended into the file over and over again.

For example I've recently configured OpenSSH to strictly only accept SSH keys and prevent any use of passwords. However, I would now like to use the **match** option to allow passwords to be used only on a specific IP address subnet. I want to append the following lines to the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** file:

```
Match Address 192.168.0.0/16
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PermitRootLogin yes
```

If these lines of code existed already, how do I check if the block of text exists as whole within the configuration file?

I can search for individual strings using grep but the **PasswordAuthentication** and **PermitRootLogin** parameters depend on the match option.

```
grep -qxF 'PasswordAuthentication yes' "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" || echo "PasswordAuthentication yes" >> "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
```

When I was new to Linux I used to make a backup of the configuration file and then cat entire heredocs into the file. Obviously I could do this as many times as I like because the configuration file always got overwritten with exactly what I need and the original was safe.

Comment: The best way to do this using include files, so you can still write the exactly content you want to your own specific file and include that in the main config. But `Include` in `sshd_config` was only added in 8.2. Which version of SSH do you have?

Comment: @muru I honestly didn't think OpenSSH had support for including external files. Obviously before the include option was included in older versions, I assume there wasn't any other alternatives?

Comment: I don't think so. But in situations like those, I'd still manage the file as a whole, and use templating of some sort (via Ansible, Puppet, etc.) to gather together snippets, instead of using text processing to manage some lines within a single file.